# Xamarin Forms - Google Credentials

Tags: c#, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Im setting up Firestore Cloud, I installed the Firestore SDK and set the enviroment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS to my google-services.json path.

The following error appears:

```
Error reading credential file from location D:\Downloads\google-services.json:
Error creating credential from JSON. Unrecognized credential type. 
Please check the value of the Environment Variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
```

I tried a lot of way to resolve but I don't resolve it. 
How can I solve this? I got the google.services.json file from Firebase.

Comment: Hi!, Have you check that the  [Environment Variable Exists](https://learn.foundry.com/nuke/content/comp_environment/configuring_nuke/environment_variables.html)?
Can you also check the content is actually JSON with `cat $GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` in Linux?

Comment: If you're trying to use the Google.Cloud.Firestore library, please be aware that Xamarin isn't a supported platform. See https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/guides/platforms.html